# How are the new stat comparisons on items calculated?

Tags: diablo-iii

[image: Diablo 3 Stat Comparisons]

With the new patch, the classic 'Life', 'Damage' and 'Proection' have been replaced with a 'Damage', 'Toughness' and 'Healing' comparison.

While 'Damage' is fairly straightforward, how are the other comparisons calculated?

Comment: I'm looking for an answer that more precisely defines the terms of these calculations - preferably with an example

Answer (score 6):

The new toughness and healing listed in your character stats are equivalent to your EHP and your regen/second (when totaling all sources including regen, loh * proc * attack speed, life steal, etc).

The % changes is now purely based on how much of a boost or loss when compared to your current gear.

The example you give shows a 13.3% overall EHP gain, a 5.6% gain in life per second.

Note I've noticed the healing attribute fluctuates a lot if you have life steal on your weapon as it doesn't count until you are actually dealing damage to something so I'd take that with a grain of salt.

As for the toughness/EHP calculation, I'd also be careful as it considers dodge as part of EHP and there are many things that can't be dodged.

Comment: Does the Toughness number account for the Monk's One With Everything passive?

Comment: @StrixVaria yes it does

Comment: What does EHP stand for? Enhance Health points?

Comment: @deutschZuid effective health pool.  Basically it means that how much raw damage you can take before you die.  For example, if you have 10000 health and enough armor/resistance reduction to reduce damage by 50%, your EHP is 20000.

Comment: @z- Now I understand your comment about the dodging.

Comment: The toughness number on the character sheet takes into account One With Everything, but the comparison does not